# Limiting Specific User Agent to Internet Explorer via Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, user-agent

I am trying to limit my site to only allow User Agents with the following to be able to hit my site:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Currently in my `.htaccess` file (`/var/www/html/`) I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily, the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) is a regular expression. So, you would need to convert this to a regex - notably, you would need to backslash-escape the literal dots and *spaces*. However, it would be easier to use the lexicographical equality operator instead, ie. `=` prefix. This then matches a literal string, not a regex.

The *spaces* in the user-agent string are a special case since the *space* is an argument separator in Apache config files. These either need to be backslash escaped (or use the `\s` shorthand character class if using a regex), or enclose the whole argument in double quotes.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The `L` flag is not required with the `F` flag - it is implied. If you specifically only want to allow that one user-agent then you don't need the `NC` flag on the condition.

Comment: Hey this actually worked, every other browser seems to get an access denied. This is awesome, I do have one potential issue though. I have a file that I have hosted on the server, I can't download or hit that "application" with that rule implemented.

I have the file hosted at /var/www/mysite/file.application

But, it seems like I get an access denied when hitting this file with Internet Explorer. I've looked at the web logs, and it still has the same user agent. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: "access denied when hitting this file with Internet Explorer ... same user agent" - that doesn't seem possible given only this one rule. So, IE can access all other files except that one file? Is `file.application` literally just one file or is it itself making additional HTTP requests under a different user-agent (although you've said that it's the "same")? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I see in your [new related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841080/403-access-denied-in-apache2-website-after-updating-htaccess-file) that you've given more information... if `file.application` is calling a dependent application `dependency.application` over HTTP then it's unlikely going to be using the same user-agent string.