# 403 Access Denied in Apache2 website after updating .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, permissions, apache2

I am unable to access retrieve files hosted on my webserver called by my application. (403 forbidden).

My Application file is hosted at /var/www/mysite/program.application. If I browse to this specific directory (IE11), I can view the program.application, but when my program.application file tries to hit /var/www/mysite/files/dependency.application, I get a 403 error. This stopped working right after I implemented the rule to my .htaccess file. Removing this rule I do not have any 403.

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4.0K Sep 10 23:37 'files'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 1.7K Sep 10 20:42  myprogram.application
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  90K Sep 10 20:56  index.html
```

Here is my current configuration in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Well then either your condition is wrong, or IE is sending a different UA than you expected.

Comment: "but when my `program.application` file tries to hit `/var/www/mysite/files/dependency.application`, I get a 403 error." - If `program.application` itself is making an HTTP request to `dependency.application` then it's unlikely going to be using the same user-agent that made the initial request to `program.application` (at least you would not expect it to be).

Comment: However, in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838536/limiting-specific-user-agent-to-internet-explorer-via-apache#comment112890845_63839735) you stated that you saw the "same user agent" in the logs. If it was "the same" then it wouldn't be blocked by the above rule - so there is certainly something amiss here.